# How to create custom border like freetransform tool in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create customized border of my container like below freetransform tool. I unable find a way to do that with flutter at the moment.

[image]

Comment: you can extend `ShapeBorder` and then override the `paint` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such kind of borders can be simply created with [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html), [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html), [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) and [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) widgets. `Column` and `Row` widget to arrange the widgets the way you want. `Container` to create the square box and lines with the help of `Expanded`.

Complete Code : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Box(),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  const Box({super.key});

  @override
  State<Box> createState() => _BoxState();
}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 300,width: 300,
          
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [Row(    
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  
                  height: 5,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ), Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  
                  height: 5,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),Container(
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,children: [
              Column(
                children: [ 
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      
                      width: 5,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      
                      width: 5,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              const Text('Your Widgets'),
              
              Column(
         
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      
                      width: 5,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      
                      width: 5,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],),
          ),Row(    
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  
                  height: 5,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ), Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  
                  height: 5,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),Container(
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          
              
          
          ],
          
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output : -

[image]